# Need to update the complete table in SQL Server 2016

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2016

I want to update the complete table with `D-` `Ntext` value wherever there are duplicate entries. I am also trying to get all the duplicate entries based on `ExternalEmployeeID` but Want to update only those historic records based on old `modifieddate`.

Currently, I am trying based on the list of records:

1. excluding the latest modified record from the update
2. Update only those historic old modified records with the same `Ntext` where need to add `D-` in front of `Ntext` value. It will look like `D-ABC123`.

```
CREATE TABLE [Employee]
(
    [RegionalEmployeeId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NText] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [ExternalEmployeeID] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [EmployeeClass] [varchar](5) NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,
    [ModifiedDate] [datetime2](7) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Employee] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([RegionalEmployeeId] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
           
INSERT INTO [Employee]([NText],[ExternalEmployeeID],[EmployeeClass],[CreatedDate],[ModifiedDate]) VALUES ('DEF567', '345', 'I', '2021-03-07', '2020-03-08'); 
INSERT INTO [Employee]([NText],[ExternalEmployeeID],[EmployeeClass],[CreatedDate],[ModifiedDate]) VALUES ('DEF567', '345', 'I', '2021-03-08', '2020-03-09'); 
INSERT INTO [Employee]([NText],[ExternalEmployeeID],[EmployeeClass],[CreatedDate],[ModifiedDate]) VALUES ('DEF567', '345', 'P', '2021-03-09', '2020-03-10'); 
INSERT INTO [Employee]([NText],[ExternalEmployeeID],[EmployeeClass],[CreatedDate],[ModifiedDate]) VALUES ('DEF567', '345', 'P', '2021-03-010', '2020-03-11'); 
INSERT INTO [Employee]([NText],[ExternalEmployeeID],[EmployeeClass],[CreatedDate],[ModifiedDate]) VALUES ('CDE234', '6789', 'O', '2021-03-03', NULL); 
INSERT INTO [Employee]([NText],[ExternalEmployeeID],[EmployeeClass],[CreatedDate],[ModifiedDate]) VALUES ('CDE234', '6789', 'I', '2021-03-04', NULL); 
INSERT INTO [Employee]([NText],[ExternalEmployeeID],[EmployeeClass],[CreatedDate],[ModifiedDate]) VALUES ('CDE234', '6789', 'P', '2021-03-05', NULL); 
INSERT INTO [Employee]([NText],[ExternalEmployeeID],[EmployeeClass],[CreatedDate],[ModifiedDate]) VALUES ('ABC123', '12345', 'I', '2021-03-01', NULL); 
INSERT INTO [Employee]([NText],[ExternalEmployeeID],[EmployeeClass],[CreatedDate],[ModifiedDate]) VALUES ('ABC123', '12345', 'I', '2021-03-02', '2020-03-02'); 
INSERT INTO [Employee]([NText],[ExternalEmployeeID],[EmployeeClass],[CreatedDate],[ModifiedDate]) VALUES ('ABC123', '12345', 'O', '2021-03-01', '2020-03-03'); 
INSERT INTO [Employee]([NText],[ExternalEmployeeID],[EmployeeClass],[CreatedDate],[ModifiedDate]) VALUES ('ABC123', '12345', 'P', '2021-03-01', NULL); 
INSERT INTO [Employee]([NText],[ExternalEmployeeID],[EmployeeClass],[CreatedDate],[ModifiedDate]) VALUES ('ABC123', '12345', 'P', '2021-03-01', '2020-03-04); 
        
--Get the duplicate ExternalEmployeeID
SELECT NText, ExternalEmployeeID 
INTO #ETemp 
FROM Employee
WHERE LEN(ExternalEmployeeID) > 1 
  AND (EmployeeClass = 'I' OR EmployeeClass = 'O' OR EmployeeClass = 'P')
GROUP BY NText, ExternalEmployeeID
HAVING COUNT(ExternalEmployeeID) > 1
        
--Find the ExternalEmployeeID need to be soft-deleted based on RegionalEmployeeId
SELECT *
FROM
    (SELECT 
         RegionalEmployeeId,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY NText, ExternalEmployeeID ORDER BY ModifiedDate DESC) AS RowNumber
     FROM 
         Employee E
     WHERE 
         NText IN (SELECT NText FROM #ETemp) 
         AND ExternalEmployeeID IN (SELECT ExternalEmployeeID FROM #ETemp)
         AND (EmployeeClass = 'I' OR EmployeeClass = 'O' OR EmployeeClass = 'P')
     ) AS T 
WHERE 
    T.RowNumber > 1
```

The expected result should be like shown below as the last one is the most recent modified record so not changing that one.

```
D-DEF567, 345, I, 2021-03-07, 2020-03-08
D-DEF567, 345, I, 2021-03-08, 2020-03-09
D-DEF567, 345, P, 2021-03-09, 2020-03-10
DEF567, 345, P, 2021-03-010, 2020-03-11
CDE234, 6789, O, 2021-03-03, NULL
CDE234, 6789, I, 2021-03-04, NULL
CDE234, 6789, P, 2021-03-05, NULL 
ABC123,12345, I, 2021-03-01, NULL
D-ABC123,12345,'I, 2021-03-02, 2020-03-02
D-ABC123', 12345, O, 2021-03-01, 2020-03-03
ABC123', 12345, P, '2021-03-01', NULL
ABC123, 12345, P, 2021-03-01, 2020-03-04
```

In the same way, I need to update the list of records if there are more duplicate records based `ExternalEmployeeID`.

Comment: please show the expected result

Comment: @Squirrel, updated with the expected result. Could you please help me?

Comment: the expected result shown is only for one employee `345` ?

Comment: @Squirrel, Yes.  I want to update the whole table based on the above scenario.

Answer (score 0):

use `row_number()` to identify the "historic" record and update when `ModifiedDate is not null`

```
 ; with emp as
 (
     select *, 
            rn = row_number() over (partition by [ExternalEmployeeID]
                    order by [ModifiedDate] desc)
     from   Employee e
)
update  emp
set     NText = case when rn > 1 and ModifiedDate is not null
                     then 'D-' + NText 
                     else NText 
                     end
from    emp
```